# How to create single pull request for multiple changes for a forked repository?

Tags: git, github

I have forked a project on GitHub in my workspace. 
Original : Org_Workspace/MyProject
Forked: MyWorkspace/MyProject
If I making any changes, it provides an option of commit and create pull request for each change.
However, I want to raise a single pull request for the changes, I have performed in MyWorkspace/MyProject.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just to be clear, you have multiple commits, and want to have a single commit to create a single pull request on?

Comment: There are multiple commits.. and want to create a single pull request to org_workspace/master .. I am getting options to create pull request against every commit, I have made

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, it sounds like you are using the GitHub Web Interface to make the changes to the files.

When doing this, you can only edit and submit a single modification at a time.

In order to change multiple files at the same time, and submit a single Pull Request, you would need to:

- clone the repository locally onto your machine
- make the changes
- push the changes back to your fork
- then submit a pull request

Answer (score 1):

Try squashing all your commits into a single commit.

Run the following:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

'X' being the number of commits you want to look at on the head, which you can choose the commits that you want to squash into one

Lets assume you have 4 commits and it looks something like this:

```
123459 - commit 4
123458 - commit 3
123457 - commit 2
123456 - commit 1
```

When you run the git rebase command you'll get something like this appearing:

```
pick 123459 commit 4
pick 123458 commit 3
pick 123457 commit 2
pick 123456 commit 1
```

You will need to change it to look like this:

```
pick 123459 commit 4
squash 123458 commit 3
squash 123457 commit 2
squash 123456 commit 1
```

When done save, and congrats you have a single commit with all your multiple commits in it, which you can then create a single pull request on.